# Modular congruences related to sums of Catalan numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, experimental-mathematics, catalan-numbers

I am curious if somebody can be helpful concerning the following
experimental observation:

There exist two rational sequences $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots$ and
$\beta_0,\beta_1,\dots$, both with values in $\mathbb Z[1/3]$
such that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{2k\choose k}\frac{k^j}{k+1}\equiv 
\alpha_j+p\beta_j\pmod{p^2}$$
for every prime number $p\equiv 1\pmod 6$ and
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{2k\choose k}\frac{k^j}{k+1}\equiv 
-(-1)^j-\alpha_j+p\beta_j\pmod{p^2}$$
for every prime number $p\equiv 5\pmod 6$.

(More precisely, the sequences $3^n\alpha_n$ and $3^n\beta_n$ are seemingly integral.)

The sequence $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots$ starts as
$$1, 0, -2/3, 4/3, -22/9, 140/27, -14, 1316/27, -17078/81, 87860/81, -1562042/243, 31323292/729, \dots$$
and the first terms $\beta_0,\beta_1,\dots$ are
$$0,0,2/3,-2,14/3,-34/3,98/3,-350/3,1526/3,-2622,46634/3,-311734/3,2316158/3,
-18920018/3,\dots$$

Let me end by remarking that one has as a special case a similar result when replacing Catalan numbers by central binomial coefficients.

Update: The existence of the sequence $\alpha_n$ is explained by the Zhi-Wei Sun paper,
see the answer by dke below.

Experimentally, the quotient sequence $\frac{\beta_n}{\alpha_n}$ (defined for $n\geq 2$)
seems to converge very quickly towards $-\frac{4\sqrt{3}\pi}{9}=-2.4183991523\dots$ (the error is
smaller than $10^{-78}$ for $n=120$).

The sequence $\frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_n}-\frac{\alpha_n}{\alpha_{n-1}}$
converges perhaps (fairly slowly) towards something like $-.72\dots$.

Comment: Roland, do you mean $-(-1)^j-\alpha_j+p\beta_j$ in the second
congruence?

Comment: Have you looked through the papers of Zhi-Wei Sun ? For instance, http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0509.5648 contains some results about $\sum k^rC_k$ mod p which may help.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to explain a part of the story.

Comment: Does anything interesting turn up when you factor the numerators? 

Comment: I don't know how far out you've done computations, but do you ever get a denominator other than 1 or 3 for the $\beta_j$?

Comment: Indeed, up to $j=25$, the denominator is at most $3$. The sequence 
$\beta_n$ has thus perhaps all its values in $\frac{1}{3}\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Concerning Gerry's question, I do not think so. There is some analytic regularity: the sequences are ultimately alternating in sign
and successive quotients seem somehow to converge to affine functions
but I did no extensive checks. Let me also add that all sequences 
are periodic modulo any odd prime $>3$ (this follows easily from
their definition).

Comment: The link in [dke's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36900/modular-congruences-related-to-sums-of-catalan-numbers#comment85932_36900) is broken, here's a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509648

Answer (score 5):

Just a quick thought about showing that $3^n\alpha_n$ is integral. It's not too hard to prove via the Catalan number generating function that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} C_kx^k\equiv \frac{1-(1-4x)^{(p+1)/2}}{2x}-x^{p-1}\quad\bmod (p,x^p).$$
Now apply $D=x\frac{d}{dx}$ a bunch of times and set $x=1$ to get the sums you want. Then by using $(-3)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv \left(\frac{p}{3}\right)\bmod p$ you can control the 3-adic valuation (you get an extra 3 for each differentiation) and see that the only dependence on $p$ is the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$ which furthermore depends only on $p$ modulo 3. There's also a 2 in the denominator but I guess by looking a bit more carefully you can show this cancels out for $p$ not equal to 3. This is a bit sketchy but hopefully the idea is there.

In particular, letting Sage do the work, I get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}C_k\equiv \frac{{\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)}-1}{2}\quad\pmod p$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}kC_k\equiv \frac{{-\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)}+1}{2}\quad\pmod p$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}k^2C_k\equiv \frac{-{\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)}-3}{6}\quad\pmod p$$
which seem to fit your sequence as well as the results in the Zhi-Wei Sun paper.

I can't see how to get at the $\beta_j$ though.

Edited to add: one can maybe do the same trick using
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} C_kx^k\equiv \frac{1-(1-4x)^{(p^2+1)/2}}{2x}-px^{p-1}\quad\bmod (p^2,x^p)$$
to get the $\beta_j$ as well, though I'm not so convinced.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder about the reason to consider
$$
A_j=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{k^j}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}
$$
instead of
$$
\tilde A_j = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} k^j \binom{2k}{k},
$$
as $A_j\pm A_0$ ($+$ for odd $j$ and $-$ for even $j$) are reduced to linear combinations of the latter. Let me introduce the functions
$$
F_j(x)=\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^j\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\binom{2k}{k}x^k,
$$
so that $\tilde A_j=F_j(1)$. Note that
$$
F_0(x)=F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\binom{2k}{k}x^k
$$
satisfies the differential equation
$$
F(x)-\frac12(1-4x)F'(x)=\frac{(2p-1)!}{(p-1)!^2}x^{p-1}.
$$
Here the coefficient on the right is
$$
\frac{(2p-1)!}{(p-1)!^2}\equiv p\pmod{p^4}
$$
by [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26137/) and we can write the equation in the form
$$
xF_0(x)-\frac12(1-4x)F_1(x)=\frac{(2p-1)!}{(p-1)!^2}x^p.
$$
Applying repeatedly the operator $x\dfrac{d}{dx}$ to both sides of the identity produces, for each $j$, a relation of the form
$$
P_{0,j}(x)F_0(x)+P_{1,j}(x)F_1(x)+\dots+P_{j-1,j}(x)F_{j-1}(x)-\frac12(1-4x)F_j(x)=p^{j-1}\frac{(2p-1)!}{(p-1)!^2}x^p,
$$
where all coefficients of the polynomials $P_{i,j}(x)$ are *integral* (and, of course, independent of $p$). This gives a way to express $\frac32F_j(1)=\frac32\tilde A_j$ as a $\mathbb Z$-linear combination of $\tilde A_0,\tilde A_1,\dots,\tilde A_{j-1}$ independently of $p$ modulo $p^j$. The remaining piece is to check that $\tilde A_0$ and $\tilde A_1$ as well as the starting $A_0$ do satisfy the "$p$-independence" property modulo $p^2$.

The construction above gives a recipe to construct recursively the sequence $\tilde A_j$ (hence $A_j$), although I do not try myself to figure out a closed-form evaluation of the auxilliary polynomials $P_{i,j}(x)$ and/or their values at $x=1$.