# Largest power of $p$ which divides $F_p=\binom{p^{n+1}}{p^n}-\binom{p^{n}}{p^{n-1}}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers

I would like to know your comments in order to obtain the largest power of the prime numberr $p$ which divides
$$
F_p= \binom{p^{n+1}}{p^n}-\binom{p^{n}}{p^{n-1}}.
$$
I proved the largest power that divided $F_2$ is $3n$.
For the case $p=2$, I could use Vandermonde's Identity. So
$$\binom{2^{n+1}}{2^n}-\binom{2^{n}}{2^{n-1}}\\
=\sum_{j=0}^{2^{n+1}}\binom{2^{n}}{j}\binom{2^{n}}{2^{n}-j}-\binom{2^{n-1}}{j}\binom{2^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}-j} $$

Answer (score 7):

It is known that $$F_2\equiv 2^{3r}\pmod{2^{3r+3}}\quad (r\ge 2),\quad F_3\equiv 3^{3r+1}\pmod{3^{3r+3}} \quad( r\ge 1),$$
$$F_p\equiv \Delta_p p^{3r+2}\pmod{p^{3r+3}} \quad (p\ge 5, r\ge 2),$$
where $\Delta_p$ depends only on $p$ (see [Jacobsthal, 
Zahlentheoretische Eigenschaften der Binomialkoeffizienten, Norske Vid. Selsk., Skr. 1942, No. 4, 28 S. (1945).](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0060.08422)). More generally
$$\binom{np}{kp}\equiv\binom{n}{k}\pmod{p^{3+\mathrm{ord}_pn+\mathrm{ord}_pk+\mathrm{ord}_p(n-k)+\mathrm{ord}_p\binom{n}{k}}}.$$
It is also known, see [Granville, Arithmetic properties of binomial coefficients. I. Binomial coefficients modulo prime powers](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/granville/) that the last exponent can only be increased  if $p$ devides $B_{p-3}$, the $(p-3)$rd Bernoulli number.

See also discussion at [Binomial supercongruences: is there any reason for them?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26137/binomial-supercongruences-is-there-any-reason-for-them)

Comment: Thank you! How can find reference to answer my question?

Comment: Probably this article is unvailable in electronic form. At least I failed to find it. I know this result only from another articles.

Comment: It would be great if I can see the English version of this article or find Doi of it!

Answer (score 6):

In point of fact, it was W. Ljunggren who proved in his 1942 paper "En egenskap ved de midtre binomialkoeffisienter" (Norsk. Mat. Tidsskrift **24** (1942), 18-22) that

$$p^{3n+\varepsilon} \mid F_{p}$$

where $\varepsilon=0$ if $p=2$, $\varepsilon = 1$ if $p=3$, and $\varepsilon =2$ if $p \geq 5$.

You can find the following sketch of Ljunggren's proof in pages 563-564 of the second volume of *The Collected Papers of Wilhelm Ljunggren*:

> In the identity
>
> $$F(y) = \prod_{\substack{\lambda =1\\ (\lambda,p)=1}}^{pm}(y-\lambda) = y^{t} -A_{1}y^{t-1} + A_{2}y^{t-2} - \ldots + A_{t-2}y^{2}-A_{t-1}y+A_{t} \quad  \quad(*)$$
>
> where $m=p^{n-1}$, $t=\varphi(p^{n})$ and $n>1$ for $p=2$, $A_{t-1}$
>   is divisible by $p^{\varepsilon} m^{2}$. This is a consequence of a
>   theorem of Leudesdorf. In ($\ast$) we first put $y=pm$. Dividing by
>   $pm$ and making use of the fact that $A_{t-1}$ is divisible by
>   $p^{\varepsilon} \cdot m^{2}$ we easily find that $A_{t-2}$ is
>   divisible by $mp^{\varepsilon-1}$. We then put $y=p^{2}m$ and thus get
>   that $F(p^{2}m)-A_{t}$ is divisible by $m^{3}p^{\varepsilon+2}$. We
>   then can give the expression [that defines $F_{p}$] in the form
>   $$\binom{p^{2}m}{pm} - \binom{pm}{m} = p\binom{pm-1}{m-1} \frac{F(p^{2}m)-A_{t}}{A_{t}}.$$
>   This gives the proof of our... theorem because $(A_{t},p)=1$.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortionly I couldn't find the  W. Ljunggren paper..

Comment: Do you mean the one he published in 1942 in Norsk. Mat. Tidsskrift? If you want a copy of it, I can send you one later today. You can find my email address in my profile page...

Answer (score 4):

Although the question was completely answered by others, I want to provide some more input.

1. An illuminating $p$-adic point of view is given in Section 7.1.6, "The Kazandzidis Congruences", of the (excellent) book "A Course in $p$-adic Analysis" by Alain M. Robert. The main result of the section is the following result, mentioned by Alexei Ustinov, and attributed there to Kazandzidis:

> $$\forall p > 2: \binom{pn}{pk} \equiv \binom{n}{k} \pmod {p^{2+\varepsilon}nk(n-k)\binom{n}{k}\mathbb{Z}_p}, \quad \varepsilon = 1_{p>3}.$$

The section is part of the chapter on the Morita $p$-adic Gamma function $\Gamma_p: \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_p$, which is a continuous function given on integers $n>2$ by
$$\Gamma_p(n)=(-1)^n \prod_{1\le j <n, p\nmid j} j,$$
at least when $p$ is an odd prime. Legendre's formula shows that the $p$-adic valuation of both terms in $F_p$ is exactly $1$, and so it remains to understand the $p$-adic valuation of
$$\binom{p^{n+1}}{p^n} / \binom{p^n}{p^{n-1}} -1,$$
which is a difference of two elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$. As mentioned in the section, L. van Hamme had observed that
$$\binom{pa}{pb} / \binom{a}{b} =\frac{\Gamma_p(pa)}{\Gamma_p(pb)\Gamma_p(p(a-b))},$$ 
and so it remains to compute
$$| \frac{\Gamma_p(pa)}{\Gamma_p(pb)\Gamma_p(p(a-b))} - 1|_p,$$
which explains the link with $p$-adic analysis. Properties of the logarithm in $\mathbb{Z}$ show that in fact the above valuation is exactly
$$|\log \Gamma_p(pa) - \log \Gamma_p(pb) - \log \Gamma_p(p(a-b))|_p.$$
Now it just a matter of finding out what is the Taylor expansion of $f(x):=\log \Gamma(px)$. It can be shown that $f$ is an odd function, as so
$$f(x) = \sum_{i \ge 1} a_i x^{2i-1},$$
and then
$$f(a)-f(b)-f(a-b)= ab(a-b)\sum_{i \ge 2} a_i \cdot \frac{a^{2i-1}-b^{2i-1}-(a-b)^{2i-1}}{ab(a-b)}.$$
(Note the vanishing of the linear term $i=1$!) The usual properties of the $p$-adic valuation yield that
$$|f(a)-f(b)-f(a-b)|_p \le |ab(a-b)|_p \cdot \max_{i \ge 2} |a_i|_p \cdot |\frac{a^{2i-1}-b^{2i-1}-(a-b)^{2i-1}}{ab(a-b)}|_p.$$
Bounding $\max_{i \ge 2} |a_i|_p \cdot |\frac{a^{2i-1}-b^{2i-1}-(a-b)^{2i-1}}{ab(a-b)}|_p$ is somewhat technical, and it is related to the Bernoulli numbers, as mentioned in Alexei's answer. It can be shown that the term $i=2$ satisfies $|a_2\cdot 3|_p \le p^{-3+1_{p=3}}$ and that the rest of the terms have valuation smaller or equal to that. This yields the Kazandzisids Congruences by the previous arguments. by plugging $a=p^n,b=p^{n-1}$, we obtain a bound on the $p$-adic valuation of your $F_p$.

2. An easy-to-follow and elementary approach to the Kazandzidis Congruences, which gives a (slightly) weaker result, is given in [Lemma A of the paper "Some Congruences For Generalized Euler Numbers"](http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/papers/gen-eul.pdf), by I. Gessel (1983):

> Let $p$ be a prime. Let $\epsilon=1$ if $p$ is 2 or 3, and $\epsilon=0$ if $p$ is greater than $3$. Then $\binom{p^ka}{p^k b} \equiv \binom{p^{k-1}a}{p^{k-1}b} \pmod {p^{3k-\epsilon}}$

It is quite possible that following Gessel's proof with the specific choice $b=1,a=p$ might allow you to recover the valuation given by Kazandzidis' result.

Comment: Kazandzidis results were published in 1948, 1968, 1969, see "The Kazandzidis Supercongruences.
A Simple Proof and an Application." by
ALAIN ROBERT and MAXIME ZUBER http://www.numdam.org/article/RSMUP_1995__94__235_0.pdf