# On Mathematicians Who Did Their Masterworks After ‎40 Years Old

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

**Remark:** ‎‎The ‎idea ‎of ‎this soft ‎question ‎is ‎adopted ‎from ‎the following interesting ‎book‎. ‎ 
‎

**Timothy Gowers, Mathematics: A Very Short Introduction, Oxford University Press, 2002.**‎ 
‎

$‎‎40$ ‎years ‎old ‎is a‎ ‎well ‎known ‎bound ‎for professional ‎mathematicians. ‎Many ‎of ‎them ‎believe ‎that ‎this ‎age ‎is ‎an ‎end ‎for a‎ ‎mathematician's masterworks. ‎Based on ‎the ‎soul ‎of ‎this ‎belief ‎many ‎of ‎the ‎most ‎famous ‎mathematical ‎awards (like fields medal) ‎are ‎just ‎for ‎mathemticians ‎who ‎are under ‎‎$40‎‎$ ‎years ‎old. ‎Now ‎my ‎question ‎is:‎ 
‎

**Question:** Do you know any mathematician who proved his/her best theorems after ‎$‎‎40$ ‎years ‎old? ‎Please ‎introduce ‎your ‎references.‎ ‎
‎

**Remark:** ‎The ‎notion ‎of "‎the ‎masterwork" ‎of ‎a mathematician ‎is ‎clear ‎by ‎the fame and ‎number ‎of ‎references ‎to it.‎
‎

Comment: This seems extremely close to [Major mathematical advances past age fifty](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25630/major-mathematical-advances-past-age-fifty)